# How to capture particular column from select statement inside a package body in oracle pl sql

Tags: regex, oracle, plsql

I have more than 10 packages in a database package body like this.

```
package pk_name  body
insert into table 
(id,
name,
roll_no)
(select 
s.id id,
case when s.name in ('ad','gd') 
then 'sam'
else 'pam' end  name,
s.rid roll_no )
```

What I need to capture is the column logic from the select clause

for example

I need  case statement from column 
**NAME**.

```
case when s.name in ('ad','gd') 
then 'sam'
else 'pam' end
```

I need to do it for all columns.

I can see all my packages in the user_source table.

I thought of using regular expression but am unable to do so.

As you see columns are separated by comma in select clause (I thought of using it as a separator) but there is chance that a comma could come inside a case statement as well. How would I cope with that?

Comment: Are the packages so big and it is not an once-only task? I mean that it is easier to do it by hands maybe

Comment: wont this works ? select * from  user_source where name ='pk_name' and TRIM(TEXT) like '%case%'  and TRIM(TEXT) like '%then%' ..?

Comment: Why can't you directly write the case statements in all 10 packages? What is the need of regular expressions?

Comment: @agent5566: Yes above is just a example  packages are really big as per my calculation it will take me 11 hours to manually do it.

Comment: @moudiz i require full logic not a single line thats why i thought of using comma as a seprator it will get the value irrespective of number of lines.

Comment: @nitish I am not allowed to modify existing package code.

Answer (score 0):

In general case the RegExp is not acceptable for this task. You should handle SQL DML syntax which is not regular (i'm not talking about pl\sql lang in assumption that we have alredy cut queries from the packages. I belive it is possible to do with PLscope and RegExp). So you have to make a choice:

1. implement or take some **full** SQL syntax parser and do what you want
2. take some assumptions that limit your task and simplify the SQL grammar and make **regular subset** of it. For example you can say that column expression could't have subqueries and so on. Then you can use RegExp.
3. make some simple and more general CFG for which SQL is a subset. Then implement **simple CFG parser** (by hand or with tools yacc\bison)

As for me i prefer the third case. But if you are not familiar with all this stuff it will take more than 11 hours for you to do something.